# Wireshark does not capture python POST request

Tags: post, python-3.x, wireshark

I have a python script which triggers a http POST request using standard libraries. I'm trying to view and debug the requests content by capturing in wireshark.

The request is sucesfull because I recieve the correct server response. 
In wireshark I listen on all available interfaces but cannot find the request.

I have also tried some filtering options like http filter but the request was still not found.

I have Ubuntu installed and the server host is not localhost

How can I find the request?

Comment: Information about your OS and the server host(is it localhost?) make sense. Please add it.

Comment: Have you found any solution for this ?? Im facing the same issue on Java

Comment: "the server host is not localhost" I.e., the server host is another computer - you're not sending the request to a server on the computer that's running the Python script?

Answer (score 2):

You are unable to capture HTTP POST request because you are using Wireshark http filters. Do not filter traffic with HTTP filters, instead of that use website/URL IP address.

I have just tried to filter the traffic with the help of Wireshark and found that I can filter it with the help of IP address.

Refer below link,
https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_requests_post.asp

[image]

[image]

Use Filter : "ip.addr==192.229.133.221"

[image]

I can filter the packets, but its TCP encrypted traffic and we cannot get additional information without decryption.

[image]

Refer below answer, it will help you to find the IP address of your URL.

[How to use filters in the wireshark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65359167/how-to-use-filters-in-the-wireshark/65440285#65440285)

If you are not comfortable with it, use “Microsoft Network Monitor” tool. It shows applications name along with IP address and ports.

[image]

Once you know the IP address and ports used, you can filter the traffic with the help of Wireshark easily.

Note:- I will suggest instead of "Wireshark" or "Microsoft Network Monitor”, please use fiddler. Refer below link,

[How to capture Visual Studio Code traffic through Fiddler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57228186/how-to-capture-visual-studio-code-traffic-through-fiddler)