# How to capture Visual Studio Code traffic through Fiddler?

Tags: visual-studio-code, fiddler

How can we capture VS Code traffic through Fiddler? I ran my Fiddler and seems working fine. It could capture browsers' traffic but not VS Code traffic. 
I really appreciate if anyone can give me the solution for that.

Thanks

Comment: What is VS Code traffic? What do you expect to capture?

Comment: Have you tried to manually configure Fiddler as Proxy in VS Code? (localhost:8888)

Comment: I want to capture any Request/Response calling any API. This is a very helpful way for debugging between different teams.

Comment: @Robert, thanks, setting `http://localhost:8888` as proxy in VS Code solves problem for me. I'm using https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=humao.rest-client extension to sent http requests and wanted to capture traffic with fiddler. I'm not sure about authors' use case.

Answer (score 8):

Assuming that you are using some REST client plugin and want to capture the traffic, This worked for me:

1. In VS Code, go to File -> Preferences -> Settings
2. In the settings Search field, type in "proxy"
3. Set the "Http: Proxy" setting to "http://localhost:8888"

Comment: Make sure Fiddler is running before (re-) starting VSCode. You may need to set up HTTPS. (Normally, Fiddler will prompt you, if it isn't set).

Comment: Not necessary, you can keep them running when you change the proxy in VS Code.

Comment: I also had to disable "Proxy Strict SSL" in VSCode. For good measure I changed "Proxy support" from override to on.