# PostAsJsonAsync C# - How to set headers correctly for POST request - BAD REQUEST 400

Tags: c#, post, http-headers, postman, basic-authentication

Hello to everyone out there.

I am having this next problem.
I am trying to do a POST request but when I am compiling and executing it with the debugger of Visual Studio Code, I am getting an error of 400 Bad Request.
Regardless of that, when I am doing the same POST request in Postman, I am getting a 200 OK status request with all the values that I need for continuing to the next part in which I am working on.
[image]

Moreover, there is a Basic Auth in the request which in this case I am including it in Postman and it works fine. From the other side, in my script with C#, I am executing it like this:

*This is my model in which all my data is included for serializing the object into JSON.

```
 public class patient{
    public string deviceId { get; set; }        
    public string deviceType { get; set; }
    public string apiVersion { get; set; }
    public string language { get; set; }
    public externUserClass externUser{ get;set; }

    public class externUserClass{
        public externUserClass(string partnerExternalId, string username, string newPassword, string gender){
            this.partnerExternalId = partnerExternalId;
            this.username = username;
            this.newPassword = newPassword;
            this.gender = gender;
        }
        public string partnerExternalId { get; set; }
        public string username { get; set; }
        public string newPassword { get; set; }
        public string gender { get; set; }
    }
    public string includeAuthToken{ get; set; }
}
```

*This is my Helper class for creating the POST request. I insert all the data that I need and then I serialize the object to JSON as some of you have adviced me to do so. It is quite cleaner.

```
 public async Task<string> HubCreateUser(string conf, string userId, string sexo, string deviceId)
    {
        var sexoStr = "";  
        if(sexo == "MALE") {
            sexoStr = "MALE";
        } else if(sexo == "FEMALE") {
            sexoStr = "FEMALE";
        }

        var guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(); // guid para el username y el password
        var data = new patient();
        data.deviceId = userId;
        data.deviceType = "WEB";
        data.apiVersion = "4.0.3";
        data.language = "es_ES";
        data.externUser = new patient.externUserClass(userId, guid, guid, sexoStr); // extern user
        data.includeAuthToken = "true";

        string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);

        var severDestination= conf;
        var client =  new HttpClient{BaseAddress = new Uri(severDestination)};
        MediaType = "application/json";
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue(MediaType)); //ACCEPT header
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =  new AuthenticationHeaderValue("xxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxxxxx");
        var Client = client;
        var request = await Client.PostAsJsonAsync("externUser", output);

        request.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        var status = await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return status;
    }
```

If anyone has any clue on how to deal with this, it would be really appreciating.
I will keep trying combinations on how to tackle with an alternative on the issue.
*Despite the modifications, I am still having the same issue. I did serialize the object and I am getting it the way I need to. But, whenever it comes to the request, it gives me a 400 Bad Request.

kind regards and thanks you

Comment: I would ignore any errors you are getting in VS until you fix the the response status of 400 and get a 200 OK.  The error is due to the server not liking the request so any processing of the response is meaningless.  The default headers in c# are different from Postman.  The best way of debugging is to use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and compare the Postman headers with the c# headers.  Then make c# look like Postman.  There are many reasons for the 400 error.  Often it is just adding the User Agent  header which specifies the type of browser your code is emulating.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with `PostAsync` instead of `PostAsJsonAsync`

```
var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

var request  = await httpClient.PostAsync(requestUrl, content);
```

Please find more details on `PostAsJsonAsync` at [HttpClient not supporting PostAsJsonAsync method C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158378/httpclient-not-supporting-postasjsonasync-method-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1):

It seems you should remove the comma of the end of the following lines:

```
sexoStr = "\"gender\": \"MALE\",";
...
sexoStr = "\"gender\": \"FEMALE\",";
```

Generally speaking, prefer working with model class and serializing them (using `Newtonsoft.Json` ([example](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm)) or `System.Text.Json`), instead of hardcoded strings.

Comment: That's one thing, I already did it. My machine for some reason  is still caching the request from before (with the comma included). I cleared my cache and cookies but there is something weird there that is still persistent. I will try serializing my JSON also. Will let you know if it worked. Thanks

Comment: Hard to believe that the POST request is cached ([see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626057/is-it-possible-to-cache-post-methods-in-http)). Do you have access to the server-side so that you could see the incoming request? if not, you should probably just use [fiddler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57228186/how-to-capture-visual-studio-code-traffic-through-fiddler) or wireshark to see it.